# Google Sheet API Update tokens?

Tags: java, caching, google-sheets, token, google-sheets-api

For god's sake I'm out of my mind right now.
I can't get to seemingly an extremely easy point, I've travelled through hundreds of web pages, but couldn't succeed in finding an answer.

I've been using Google Sheet API (Java lang), and when I started it was all fine and working. And is still working, but the problem is - I need to change my account. Because of reasons, no other way

I'm copying all the new credentials, doing step-by-step what the Quickstart says, but yet every time I try to get access to the spreadsheet I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:576)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:493)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

I've tried deleting tokens folder. Even tried to create a totally new project. Nothing works.

Where does the problem hide? In browsers? What browser? I'm using Safari (which is default), but I've got Chrome on my Mac too.

Please help, I'm desperate, it's deadline today

Comment: You are talking about using browser but show errors from a Java stacktrace? It is unclear wehere your problem is. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No I'm not talking about using browsers. I'm talking about Java interacting with Google Sheet API and via service.spreadsheets().values().update(...).execute(); writing data to it.

So if I'm working with the first account I logged in (when I just started using sheet api on my mac), and attempting to write data into spreadsheets on this account, it works without any problems. But when I try to change my account and attempt to write data into sheets on another account, it throws 401 unauthorized exception.

So that's what I'm saying, I update my credentials and delete tokens/ folder, nothin

Comment: Where's your code that handles auth? Did you change project scopes but have a serialized `refresh_token` somewhere?